# Recover data from R CMD BATCH

Tags: r, batch-processing

is there a way to recover the workspace after using  R CDM BATCH ?

Say I have an `example.R` file:

```
data = rnorm(10)
```

and I run:

```
R CMD BATCH example.R &
```

is there a way to access `data` once the operation is terminated ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A file named `.RData` should be created in the directory where you run the batch command. When starting R from this directory, the workspace should be loaded at startup. Alternatively can reload the workspace manually

```
R .RData
```

or, from within R:

```
load('.RData')
```

If you want to control the file name where your workspace is saved to, you can use `?save.image` in your R script:

```
save.image(file="filename.RData")
```

Comment: well it's wired I can't view it when typing `ls`but it is apparently here as when I do `find` it is listed. What should I do ? i'm not an expert with batch command

Comment: Can you see it with `ls -a`?

Comment: yes I do, but how can I use it then ? when I try `R .RData` it says `ARGUMENT '.RData' __ignor__`

Comment: If you just start R from that directory, does it tell you `[Previously saved workspace restored]`? What operating system are you using?

Comment: you got it, no need to specify `.RData` it is done automatically